# how to prevent spaces from being counted at the start of a keyup in the text area with jquery?

Tags: jquery, string-length, keyup

like twitter, when the textarea is blank and only spaces are typed, the spaces are not counted, but after the first letter is typed, the spaces are counted.

in this script the count runs even if only spaces are typed.

So how to prevent spaces from being counted at the start of a keyup?

```
function updateCountdown() {
    // 140 is the max message length
    var remaining = 140 - $('.message').val().length;
    $('.countdown').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
}

$(document).ready(function($) {
    updateCountdown();
    $('.message').change(updateCountdown);
    $('.message').keyup(updateCountdown);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use key code.

First you have to change your keyup event trigger.

```
$('.message').keyup((e) => updateCountdown(e));
```

Then in function add this statement:

```
function updateCountdown(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
      //user pressed space key.
   }
   // 140 is the max message length
   var remaining = 140 - $('.message').val().length;
   $('.countdown').text(remaining + ' characters remaining.');
   }
```

Alternatively you can use [trim](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) to avoid first and last space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim the string. So instead of:

```
$(".message").val().length
```

You would want the following instead:

```
$(".message").val().trim().length
```

Trimming takes out any whitespace before and after strings so the main content is what gets returned.